# jQuery $('#id').submit() not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am creating a form such that when the user click the "submit" button, it prevents the default action, serializes a subset of the fields, and then proceeds to submit all of the information via the POST array (PHP).

I am encountering a problem where the form is basically not submitting when I use the .submit() method. When I disable my javascript, the form submits fine (just with the wrong information, as the array is not serialized). But as soon as I re-enable my js, clicking the submit button does nothing except show my test console.log(var) in console. Here is some of my code, hopefully you can see what I am doing wrong. All of the online documentation says to use .submit(), but it doesn't seem to work, no matter what I try.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="entryForm" action="add_entry.php" method="post">
        <div class="leftDiv">
        <input type="text" class="inputFormTitle" name="entryName" placeholder="Name your entry..." />
        <span class="regText">
        <b>Entry Properties</b>
        Specify entry properties, permissions, etc.</span>
        <table class="formTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Parameter</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        <tr>
            <td>Group</td>
            <td><select name="group"><option></option><option>Graham Test</option></select>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Project</td>
            <td><select name="project"><option></option><option>Project 1</option><option>Project 2</option></select>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Protocol</td>
            <td>        
                <select id="protocolloader" name="protocol">
                <option></option>
                <option>PCR & Gel</option>
                <option>Item Storage</option>
        <tr>
            <td>Permissions</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="permission" value="0">Only I can access this entry</input>
                <input type="radio" name="permission" value="1">Only group members can access this entry</input>

                <input type="radio" name="permission" value="2">Everyone can access this entry</input>

        </select>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" id="submitEntry" style="font-family:Raleway;" class="inputButton" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit Entry" /
        <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="rightDiv">      
        <input type="text" class="inputFormTitle" id="ppt" placeholder="Please select a protocol" disabled/>
        <div class="formHolder" id="protocolForm">
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="serialInput" name="protocolValues" value="nuttin" />
    </form>
```

**And the accompanying javascript:**

```
var entrySubmit = $('#submitEntry');
entrySubmit.on('click', initEntrySubmission);

function initEntrySubmission(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var serializedProtocol = $("#protocolForm :input").serialize();
    console.log(serializedProtocol);
    $('#serialInput').val(serializedProtocol);
    $('#entryForm').submit();
}
```

**PHP Form (which I don't think is the issue but figured I would include it anyways)**

```
<?php // add_entry.php

session_start();

include_once 'creds.php';
$con=mysqli_connect("$db_hostname","$db_username","$db_password","$db_database");

if (isset($_POST['group'])){

$lab = $_SESSION['labname'];
$author = $_SESSION['username'];
$name = $_POST['entryName'];
$group = $_POST['group'];
$protocol = $_POST['protocol'];
$permission = $_POST['permission'];
$array = $_POST['serialInput'];
$filearray = $_POST['fileArray'];
$project = $_POST['project'];



    $query = "INSERT INTO data (protocol, name, lab, author, uniquearray, filearray, group, project, permissionflag) 
                    VALUES ('$protocol', '$name', '$lab', '$author', '$array', '$filearray', '$group', 'project', '$permission')";

    mysqli_query($con, $query);

    mysqli_close($con);

}

?>
```

I wouldn't normally include so much HTML but I thought maybe I messed something up in there that may be the issue, and I just don't realize it. I tried to take out most of the break and header tags to clean up the code a bit.

Thanks for any help!

Regards.

Comment: where do you call your initentrysubmission function? Your closing tag is not there to that may be why its not getting called.

Comment: your submit button isn't closed. it's missing >

Comment: Your input button is missing the closing `>`. Also you defined its `type` as `button` and also as `submit` which is wrong

Comment: *Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures.* `<input .... name="submit"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following to work:

```
<script>
function initEntrySubmission() {
  var serializedProtocol = $("#protocolForm :input").serialize();
  alert(serializedProtocol);
  $('#serialInput').val(serializedProtocol);
  return true;
}
</script>

<form id="entryForm" action="" method="post" onSubmit="return initEntrySubmission();">
...
<input type="submit" id="submitEntry" style="font-family:Raleway;" class="inputButton" value="Submit Entry"/>
</form>
```

The main things to do are to add an onSubmit to your form tag. The function must return either true or false. Return true will submit the form.

Also, you do need to clean up your HTML, there are select statements in there, without closing tags and your submit button

```
<input type="submit" id="submitEntry" style="font-family:Raleway;" class="inputButton" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit Entry" /
```

has no ending `>`, it also has 2 type attributes `type="button"` and `type="submit"`(its both a button and a submit?) and has a `name=submit`, which is also unnecessary .

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't realize 'true' or 'false' must be returned and these can be specified through a javascript event. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of `.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) states, that

> Forms and their child elements **should not use** input **names** or ids that conflict with properties of a form, **such as** ***submit***, length, or method. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures.

You have an `input` that has the `name` `submit`.

```html
<input type="submit" id="submitEntry" style="font-family:Raleway;" class="inputButton" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit Entry" />
```

I tried it with and without that name. It works without!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I read the documentation but must have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to `preventDefault()`, the Code will still be run before the Form is submitted.

```
function initEntrySubmission() {
    var serializedProtocol = $("#protocolForm :input").serialize();
    console.log(serializedProtocol);
    $('#serialInput').val(serializedProtocol);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
$('#entryForm').submit();
```

To:

```
$('#entryForm')[0].submit();
```

**Also rename your submit element as @Matmarbon has so eloquently explained.**

**Explanation:**

`$('#entryForm').submit();` simply triggers the `submit` event and takes you back to square one.

`$('#entryForm')[0].submit();` submits the form ... more like the default action, without triggering the `submit` event.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it once the dev server is running again. What does this change do? Is it seen as an array, and I am submitting element 0 of that array?

Comment: `$('#entryForm')[0]` essentially equals `document.getElementById('entryForm')`. So the difference actually is, that you do not [trigger the event through jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) anymore but directly (if that is supported by your browser) through the [DOM elements `submit` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

**In HTML just add**

```
<form id="entryForm" action="add_entry.php" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
```

**And in JS function**

```
function initEntrySubmission(e) {
    var serializedProtocol = $("#protocolForm :input").serialize();
    $('#serialInput').val(serializedProtocol);
    $('#entryForm').removeAttr('onsubmit');
    $('#entryForm').submit();
}
```